# UbuntuにインストールしたELANで、動画ファイルが読み込めません。

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

Linux (Ubuntu) を使い始めたばかりなのですが、動画解析ソフトのELANがうまく使えなくて困っています。

ELAN自体はdebファイルを使ってインストールを行い起動することもできたのですが、動画を読み込もうとするとうまくいきません。
VLCメディアプレーヤーとlibvlc-devもインストールしました。

動画はMP4やMPEGなどを試してみましたが、どれもうまくいきません。

**MP4の場合**
ELANで動画を読み込もうとしたときに出るエラーメッセージ

```
No player could be created for:
-file:///home/test.MP4
java.lang.Runtime Exception: Failed to get at new native library instance
JFXMediaPlayer cannot handle the file:com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: could not create player!
```

読み込もうとしたファイルを調べた結果は、以下の通りです。

file コマンドの結果:

```
test.MP4: ISO Media, MPEG-4 (.MP4) for SonyPSP
```

ffmpeg コマンドの結果:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : MSNV
    minor_version   : 22675568
    compatible_brands: MSNVmp42isom
    creation_time   : 2018-12-11T07:51:39.000000Z
  Duration: 01:02:38.25, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2862 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709/bt709/iec61966-2-4), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2732 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-12-11T07:51:39.000000Z
      handler_name    : Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-12-11T07:51:39.000000Z
      handler_name    : Sound Media Handler
```

**MPEGの場合**
エラーメッセージ

```
No player could be created for:
-file:///home/test.mpeg
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc
JFXMeidaPlayer cannot handle the file: Unrecognized file signature!
```

読み込もうとしているファイルを調べた結果は、以下のとおりです。

file コマンドの結果：

```
test.mpeg: MPEG sequence, v2, program multiplex
```

ffmpeg コマンドの結果：

```
Input #0, mpeg, from 'test.mpeg':
  Duration: 00:41:33.33, start: 0.529978, bitrate: 2552 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
```

### 追記

MP4の場合に出るエラーと、ファイル情報を追記しました。